# pandas parallel urllib request for Loop

Tags: json, pandas, parsing, dataframe, urllib

i have a code to parse JSON data through API using urllib as the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import urllib.request
import os
import time
import csv
import datetime
    # Send URL Request & Get JSON Data
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

    # Select Data from result section
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data['result'])
# tickers = df['MarketName']
tickers= ["BTC-1ST", "BTC-2GIVE", "BTC-ABY", "BTC-ARDR", "BTC-WAVE"]
print(tickers)

for ticker in tickers:
    with urllib.request.urlopen("https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=" + ticker + "&tickInterval=thirtyMin") as URL:
        data = json.loads(URL.read().decode())
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data['result'])
        Market01 = "Market"
        df2[Market01] = ticker
        df2.to_csv('all.csv', encoding="utf-8-sig", index=False, mode='a', header=False)
        print("done " + ticker)
```

actually it's not request for five currency only .. they are 295 request for 295 currency .. which take 5 minutes to complete all required data to csv file (very long time)

i wonder if there are a method to send all requests in parallel to decrease time with the same option to save data to csv file as dataframe

i searched many times and found multiprocessor module but couldn't found a sample similar to my case

any one can help me please!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import urllib.request
import os
from urllib import parse
import csv
import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
import time

    # Send URL Request & Get JSON Data
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

    # Select Data from result section
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data['result'])
# tickers = df['MarketName']
tickers= ["BTC-1ST", "BTC-2GIVE", "BTC-ABY", "BTC-ARDR", "BTC-WAVE"]
print(tickers)

def http_get(url):
  result = {"url": url, "data": urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=5).read()}
  return result

urls = [ "https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=" + ticker + "&tickInterval=thirtyMin" for ticker in tickers ]

pool = Pool(processes=5)

results = pool.map(http_get, urls)

for result in results:
    j = json.loads(result['data'].decode())
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=j)
    Market01 = "Market"
    marketName = parse.parse_qs(parse.urlparse(result['url']).query)['marketName'][0]
    df2[Market01] = marketName
    df2.to_csv('all.csv', encoding="utf-8-sig", index=False, mode='a', header=False)
    print("done " + marketName)
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution .. thanks bro .. it works fine

Comment: Nice. Then please feel free to accept/upvote my answer.

Comment: hello bro .. I found that second df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data['result']) get me data result of first url https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries") .. not the required second url https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=" + ticker + "&tickInterval=thirtyMin .. tried to rename each data and url variables individual to seperate them .. but this didn't work .. kindly can you help please

Comment: I have updated the code. There was a mistake, it was always reading the result of the first service call, now it works properly.

Comment: thanks dear .. but please modify your answer `df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=j)` to `df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=j['result'])` .. thanks again